# Diameter of a Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I was doing the sample test of interviewstreet.com. It comes with 3 questions and these are publicly available. So I see no harm discussing these questions.

My question is

Question 2 / 3 (Diameter of Tree)
The diameter of a tree is the number of nodes on the longest path between two leaves in the tree. The diagram below shows a tree with diameter nine, the leaves that form the ends of a longest path are shaded (note that there is more than one path in each tree of length nine, but no path longer than nine nodes).

[image: tree]

In particular, note that the diameter of a tree T is the largest of the following quantities:

- the diameter of T's left subtree
- the diameter of T's right subtree
- the longest path between leaves that goes through the root of T

Given the root node of the tree, return the diameter of the tree

Sample Test Cases:

Input #00: Consider the tree:

[image: tree2]

Output #00:
5

Explanation:
The diameter of the tree is 5

My Answer in C++ is:

```
int traverse(node* r) {
    if (r == NULL) { return 0;}
    return max(traverse(r->left),traverse(r->right))+1;
}
int diameterOfTree(node * r) {
    return traverse(r->left)+traverse(r->right)+1;
}
```

There are 14 test cases, however 2 of them are wrong with this answer. I could not find what cases am I missing. I don't really think it is a base case, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have the diameter of a tree not passing through its root. imagine this tree:

```
             / E - F - G - H - I
A - B - C - D  
             \ J - K - L - M
```

(Sorry for the ugly ASCII art). Here the diameter is `I-H-G-F-E-D-J-K-L-M`.

Comment: The initial call is done as `diameterOfTree(root);` So I don't really think that's the case.

Comment: You did not understand me. You have cases where the diameter does not pass through the root. See my example.

Comment: Sorry, just saw the update. I see what you mean now.

Comment: What would be the diameter in this case? 13 or 10?

Comment: @Sarp Kaya According to this: *The diameter of a tree is the number of nodes on the longest path between two leaves in the tree.* it will be 10.

Comment: @PhamTrung I have provided no code I simply drew a tree that is counter-example of the proposed solution. I know how to find the diameter of a tree but this is not part of the question.